# Closed form of $f(z) = \prod_{n\in\mathbb Z} \frac{z-n-\bar\alpha}{z-n-\alpha} \times \frac{-z-n-\alpha}{-z-n-\bar\alpha}$

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

For $\alpha\in\mathbb C$ with $\mathrm{Im}(\alpha)>0$, consider the infinite product
$$f(z) = \prod_{n\in\mathbb Z} \frac{z-n-\bar\alpha}{z-n-\alpha} \times \frac{-z-n-\alpha}{-z-n-\bar\alpha}.$$
This infinite product is well-defined since each term is $1+O(1/n^2)$ for $n\to\infty$ for fixed $z\in\mathbb C$.

Is there any closed form for $f$?

Comment: Start by rewriting the expression as a product of two products, then try to find a closed form of each product.

Comment: Specifically, use $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_n=a_0\prod_{n=1}^\infty(a_n a_{-n})$ and the infinite product for $\color{blue}{\sin}$: $$f(z)=\frac{\sin\pi(\bar\alpha-z)\sin\pi(\alpha+z)}{\sin\pi(\alpha-z)\sin\pi(\bar\alpha+z)}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $\beta=\bar\alpha$
$$F(z)=\prod_{n=0}^p \frac{n-z+\beta }{n-z+\alpha}\,\,\frac{n+z+\alpha}{n+z+\beta }$$
$$F(z)=\frac{\prod_{n=0}^p (n-z+\beta)  } {\prod_{n=0}^p (n-z+\alpha) }\frac{\prod_{n=0}^p (n+z+\alpha)  } {\prod_{n=0}^p (n+z+\beta) }$$ Using Pochhammer symbols
$$F(z)=\frac{(z+\alpha ) (z-\beta ) }{(z-\alpha ) (z+\beta )    }\,\,\color{red}{\frac{(\alpha +1+z)_p (\beta +1-z)_p}{   (\alpha +1-z)_p (\beta +1+z)_p}}$$ Take logarithms of the pieces of the red part and use
$$\log \left[(A)_p\right]=p \,(\log (p)-1)+\left(A-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (p)+\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi
   }}{\Gamma (A)}\right)+$$ $$\frac{6 (A-1) A+1}{12 p}-\frac{(A-1) A (2 A-1)}{12 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$  Remembering that $X=e^{\log(X)}$ you will easily obtain the asymptotics of $F(z)$.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! Now I can obtain $f(z)$.